# Is there any language that compiles into xslt and makes it simpler to use and support it

Tags: xslt

XSLT is a very powerful tool, but using it can be painful... even with [zencoding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/).

Roughly I want a coffeescript for xslt, something that will compile for example

```
template test
  params = {:foo => 'foo', :bar => 1}
  <p>$foo, $bar</p>
end

call test :foo => 'oof', :bar => 2
```

into

```
<xsl:call-template name="test">
    <xsl:with-param select="'oof'" name="foo"></xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param select="2" name="bar"></xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="test">
  <xsl:param select="'foo'" name="foo" />
  <xsl:param select="1" name="bar" />
    <p><xsl:value-of select="$foo" />, <xsl:value-of select="$bar" /></p>
</xsl:template>
```

or something...

Comment: I would strongly recommend to avoid any such "tool" because there is no guarantee that it conveys and preserves the full meaning and functionality of the XSLT language. Much better than using such tools is to use a good XSLT IDE such as the XSelerator, Visual Studio or oXygen.

Comment: Use an editor with schema driven code completion. For instance, in Visual Studio you type `<xsl:ch`, then TAB twice, and you get `<xsl:choose><xsl:when test="token"></xsl:when></xsl:choose>`.

Comment: Of course I mean some tool, that preserves the full "XSLT meaning and functionality". Those IDE-s are good to create xsl, but while working with it you still has a lot of code to view and edit.

Answer (score 1):

You may check [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).

It can help you to generate XSL templates.

For example:

```
xml sel -C -t -c "xpath0" -m "xpath1" -m "xpath2" -v "xpath3" -t -m "xpath4" -c "xpath5"
```

will generate

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="t1"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="t2"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="t1">
    <xsl:copy-of select="xpath0"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="xpath1">
      <xsl:for-each select="xpath2">
        <xsl:value-of select="xpath3"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="t2">
    <xsl:for-each select="xpath4">
      <xsl:copy-of select="xpath5"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```